# Number of "mutations" in Omicron variant

Tags: mutations, coronavirus

Currently in the media they say that the Omicron variant has more than 30 "mutations", ie changes in spikes. I find this confusing, because the way I understand a single change in the virus can alter more than one spike in one go. I assume there is some randomness to mutations. So one mutation (new copy) can change 2 spikes, another can change 0 or 5.

Is it misleading?

Comment: Welcome to Biology StackExchange! I don't think I understand what you mean with _"a single change in the virus can alter more than one spike in one go"_. All of the spike proteins that build a virus particle are (more or less) identical, because they are a product of the same gene – there is only one gene for S protein in the SARS-CoV-2 genome. Therefore, if there is a mutation in the S gene, all the spike proteins produced will carry this same change.

Comment: I think the OP does not understand what *spike* means in the context of a coronavirus. Spike is the name of one of the important proteins of the virus and it is around 1200 amino acids long. Three copies of this protein form the characteristic surface structures of the virus well known from cartoon drawings.

Answer (score 4):

Mutations are generally random, yes, but the "30 mutations" referred to are not random *among* omicron-variant virions, but rather 30 differences between the omicron variant and the reference genome they are comparing to from early in the pandemic. Most omicron virions will have the same 30 "mutations" as all the others, because that's why that group was given a name. These are not *new mutations* in every virion, they are mutations that happened earlier in the lineage that were passed down to all the descendants of that lineage. They are only "mutations" in comparison to the reference genome. If it helps, substitute the word "differences" for "mutations": Omicron has 30 differences in the genome coding for the spike protein compared to the reference strain of SARS-CoV-2.

For a single virion, the cell it infects is going to produce all spike proteins that are the same, because they are built from the same genetic template. You wouldn't typically have multiple spikes of different types in the same virus particle (theoretically possible with errors, etc, of course).

Since the pandemic started, an incomprehensible number of different mutations have occurred in SARS-CoV-2 virions replicating in human hosts. However, most of these mutations are not consequential because they did not spread in the population. For ones that *do* spread, you can track their origin in a sort of "family tree". See for example on NextStrain:

https://nextstrain.org/groups/neherlab/ncov/21K.Omicron

Answer (score 0):

Bryan Krause has the answer, but I wanted to add a note about the connotation of the word mutation and what it actually means.

The word mutation just means genetic change that a cell (or virus) doesn't fix by the time it replicates itself. That's it. There are a few different ways to skin this cat, but the situation you're imagining is if the virion (viral genes) copied itself multiple times, called polyploidy. The thing is that mRNA viruses don't really have the ability to do that, because they can't self replicate, and so the required mechanism is off limits until they infect someone. When you say that a mutation could double the number of spike proteins, it makes me think that you assume that more genes = more proteins. While this is sometimes the case, what determines how many proteins (called protein products) come from genes is their level of expression and regulation.

So, what determines how many spike proteins a virus makes depends on how well the virus can convince the host to make more spike proteins, which might come from a mutation in a gene, but having multiple genes is not always the source of multiple copies of a protein. If we want more protein, we need more mRNA, which means we need more expression of a gene. You might say, well more copies of the viral mRNA would produce more proteins right? Yes, true, but again in a situation like that, you're really describing a higher viral load (just more of the same virus) than an instance where an entire viral genome has spontaneously doubled itself.

Some people interpret mutations, because of entertainment, as the source of genetic change responsible for dramatic differences that are cartoonish and comical. Think of the cyclopes from Futurama, for example. But no, mutations are often no so exaggerate in their appearance. Most mutations, in fact, are unhelpful and depending on how often mutations are produced in a species, are typically selected against quickly. This is an indication of two things:

1. The 30 or so mutations you report are the source of differences in traits that give the virus an advantage. Yes a mutation in a *Hox* gene for example could result in drastically different results. But more often, mutations that are helpful come in more subtle and less dramatic forms.
2. A variant of the virus is identified based on its genetics. Each variant of the virus is classified by its genome. So yes, the Omicron variant might produce a slightly different antigenic site than the Delta variant. We're not changing the number of spike proteins, we're changing the identity of the virus.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).